# Acumatica kit assembly customization

Tags: acumatica

I'm currently customizing the kit assembly and i want to add another field but my problem is when I save it nothing happen, my custom field wont saved on the database. [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB7hy.png)

Comment: are you sure it's not unbound field ? can you show your DAC extension unit ?

Comment: Add the code of your DAC / DAC extension, especially attributes of your new field.

Comment: to get the best response, you should include the code you have implemented so far. My initial guess is you are using a non DB type (and unbound field) and those are not saved to the database.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB7hy.png
Yes Im sure that i'm not using unbound field. INKitRegister doesn't exist in the database and all the information in kit assembly was saved in KitRegister. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

INKitRegister is just a PXProjection of INTran Inner Joined to INRegister.

Follow these steps to get the functionality you desire.

Add this to your Project XML

```
<Table TableName="INTran">
    <Column TableName="INTran" ColumnName="UsrStart" ColumnType="date" AllowNull="True" IsNewColumn="True" IsUnicode="True" />
</Table>
```

This will add the field to INTran. If you want it to be in INRegister change the `TableName="INTran"` part of the `Table` and `Column` tags to `INRegister`

Here is an example of what your CacheExtension should look like if you put the field in INTran

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using System;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class INTranExtension : PXCacheExtension<INTran>
    {

        #region UsrStart
        public abstract class usrStart : IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXDBTime(DisplayMask = "T", UseTimeZone = false)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start")]
        public virtual DateTime? UsrStart { get; set; }
        #endregion

    }

    public class INKitRegisterExtension : PXCacheExtension<INKitRegister>
    {

        #region UsrStart
        public abstract class usrStart : IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXDBTime(DisplayMask = "T", UseTimeZone = false, BqlField = typeof(INTranExtension.usrStart) /*When dealing with PXProjections the BqlField property tells Acumatica which DAC the field actually comes from*/)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start")]
        public virtual DateTime? UsrStart { get; set; }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Be sure to publish the Customization Project after editing the Project XML before rebuilding your project in order for the field to be properly added to the DB, otherwise, trying to access any screen referencing these DAC's will error due to the field not existing in the DB.

With the provided code, you may access the field using any View in a Screen Customization which uses the INTran DAC, or the INKitRegister DAC.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Hi @Shadow, Instead of using INRegister table, I have created a extension table with few columns with default system column, when we select inventory then i am showing a checkbox checked and a value in a Textbox, but checkbox doesn't checked and textbox is also now showing value. I am assign all properties on FieldUpdated event of inventoty, what i am missing? 
I have added a tab and then formview, inside a FORMView i have added checkbox and Textbox but values are not showing. what am i missing?